# Proper cancellation of Tasks in View Model

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, concurrency

When using MVVM architecture in Swift for iOS (or for KMM iOS part), is it needed to cancel the Tasks inside of View Model manually or will the iOS do that automatically?

If I need to do it manually, what is the right place to cancel the task (*eligibilityCheckJob* below)

- **deinit()** method of my AppInitViewModel? or
- **onDisappear()** method of my AppInitScreen view = which calls *onCleared()* in AppInitViewModel?

Here is my code snippet for reference:

```
struct AppInitScreen: View {

    private let s: Services

    @StateObject
    var viewModel: AppInitViewModel
    
    init(s: Services) {
        self.s = s
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: AppInitViewModel(networkService: s.networkService))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        AppInitScreenContents(
            uiState: viewModel.uiState,
            uiListener: viewModel
        )
        .onDisappear{
            print("AppInitScreen: onDisappear")
            viewModel.onCleared()
        }
    }
    
}

.....

extension AppInitScreen { 
    
    class AppInitViewModel: ObservableObject, AppInitScreenStateIListener { 
        
        private var networkService: NetworkService
        
        @Published 
        private(set) var uiState =  AppInitScreenState(showWelcomeText: true, showProgressBar: false)
        
        private var eligibilityCheckJob: Task<(), Error>? = nil
        
        init(networkService: NetworkService) {
            self.networkService = networkService
        }
        
        @MainActor //all code inside will be executed on main UI thread
        func onNextButtonClick() { //method from AppInitScreenStateIListener
            uiState = uiState.doCopy(
                showWelcomeText: false,
                showProgressBar: uiState.showProgressBar
            )
            processEligibilityCheck()
        }
        
        @MainActor
        func onBackButtonClick() { //method from AppInitScreenStateIListener
            eligibilityCheckJob?.cancel()
            //reset to initial state
            uiState = AppInitScreenState(
                showWelcomeText: true,
                showProgressBar: false
            )
        }
        
        @MainActor
        private func processEligibilityCheck() {
            eligibilityCheckJob = Task {
                
                //show progress indicator
                uiState = uiState.doCopy(showWelcomeText: uiState.showWelcomeText, showProgressBar: true)
                
                let isInternetAvailable: KotlinBoolean
                do {
                    isInternetAvailable = try await networkService.isInternetAvailable()
                } catch {
                    isInternetAvailable = false
                }
                if(isInternetAvailable.boolValue) { 
                    //...more code
                }
                
                //hide progress indicator
                uiState = uiState.doCopy(showWelcomeText: uiState.showWelcomeText, showProgressBar: false)

            }
            
        }
        
        func onCleared() { //called from onDisappear of AppInitScreen
            print("AppInitViewModel: onCleared")
            eligibilityCheckJob?.cancel() //IS THIS NEEDED HERE?

        }
        
        deinit {
            print("AppInitViewModel: deinit")
            eligibilityCheckJob?.cancel() //OR IS THIS NEEDED HERE?
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I have tried both ways (with task cancellation and without) on emulator but have not encountered any memory leaks.

**UPDATE 1**

@Rob have suggested to use .task modifier of the view itself. I wanted to keep the code in my View Model however so I created extension function below. Is it ok to use it like this? I would not like to break the MVVM pattern.

```
extension AppInitScreen {
    ///Extension function to launch task via .task modifier of the screen View. The task will follow View lifecycle (it does not need to be canceled manually). Use for fire-and-forget tasks.
    func launchTask(priority: TaskPriority = .userInitiated, _ action: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void) -> some View { //needs import SwiftUI
        return self.task(priority: priority, action)
    }
    
    class AppInitScreen: ObservableObject, AppInitScreenStateIListener {
        //...
        @MainActor
        private func processEligibilityCheck() {
            screenView.launchTask {
                //...
                isInternetAvailable = try await networkService.isInternetAvailable()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Code with launchTask from UPDATE 1 requires to pass View to the View Model, and that breaks the MVVM pattern. The task is being fired when button is pressed not when View appears so I have not used .task modifier. I ended up with:

- manually canceling long running tasks in *onDisappeared()* (*onCleared()*).
- not caring about short running tasks, which will just cancel when finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr

The `deinit` approach may not work for reasons outlined below. Manually canceling that [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) from `onDisappear` is often what we have to do. The exception is `.task` view modifier which will cancel its tasks automatically (when combined either with structured concurrency or unstructured concurrency wrapped in a `withTaskCancellationHandler`).

---

While `deinit` has an intuitive appeal, it frequently cannot be relied upon in this sort of scenario. Consider our looping through the `NotificationCenter` asynchronous sequence, `notifications`:

```swift
@MainActor
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask: Task<Void, Never>?

    deinit {
        didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask?.cancel()       // we’ll never get here!!! 
    }

    func startMonitoringNotificationCenter() {
        didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask = Task {
            for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification) {
                didEnterBackground()
            }
        }
    }

    private func didEnterBackground() { … }
}
```

If you `startMonitoringNotificationCenter`, you have a strong reference cycle, and thus `deinit` cannot be called. (This problem is exacerbated by the fact that unlike standard closures, there is no reference to `self` here to bring your attention to the potential strong reference cycle.)

So you really need to give your view model (or whatever) a function to clean up after itself, and call it from the view’s `didDisappear`:

```swift
@MainActor
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask: Task<Void, Never>?

    func cleanUp() {
        didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask?.cancel()
    }

    func startMonitoringNotificationCenter() {
        didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask = Task {
            for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification) {
                didEnterBackground()
            }
        }
    }

    private func didEnterBackground() { … }
}
```

Now I used an `AsyncSequence` as my example in order to manifest a persistent strong reference cycle that will never be resolved unless we explicitly `cancel` it. (I did this to bring the problem into stark relief.) But the same is for any `Task` instances that (implicitly or explicitly) keeps a strong reference to the view model object: Until these sorts of tasks all finish (or we manually cancel them), the object in question may not be able to be deallocated.

So, in short, manually cancel these in `onDisappear`.

---

FWIW, there is a [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) modifier that will automatically cancel any structured concurrency (or unstructured concurrency wrapped in a [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)/)) when you dismiss the view in question. E.g.

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = DetailViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .task {
                await viewModel.startMonitoringNotificationCenter()
            }
    }
}

@MainActor
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func startMonitoringNotificationCenter() async {
        for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification) {
            didEnterBackground()
        }
    }

    private func didEnterBackground() { … }
}
```

No manual cancelation is required. No `deinit`. No `onDisappear`. The `.task` modifier will start an asynchronous task when the view appears and then automatically `cancel` it when it disappears.

This `.task` view modifier obviously can only propagate cancelation within *structured* concurrency, but in those scenarios, the `.task` view modifier is an elegant solution.

Comment: Is the .task modifier called when the view appears - like onAppear?

Comment: Yes. Or more precisely, just before it appears. But, unlike [`onAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)), the [`task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) takes an `async` closure (and, as I already mentioned, cancels it when the view is dismissed).

Comment: The .task modifier sounds great, although i wanted to keep the logic inside my View Model.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But, as the philosopher said, “it is what it is.” In general, as much as we’d like to do it in `deinit`, that simply is not a viable technique. So, having the owner of the view model initiate the cleanup (either manually or via `.task` modifier) is what we’re stuck with.

Comment: Now, `.task` is such a nice solution, that we should definitely avail ourselves of that where appropriate. It’s a no-brainer. With other short-lived tasks that the new model initiates, you need to decide if the task is sufficiently slow and/or resource hungry that you really need to cancel it. If so, initiate that cleanup when the view is dismissed. If not, let it run. That having been said, I personally always `cancel` tasks as soon as they outlive their usefulness. Keeps everything simple, consistent, and efficient.

Comment: // we’ll never get here!!! because of retain cycle. `didEnterBackgroundNotificationTask = Task { [weak self] in ... ` to fix it

Comment: @MaxGribov - Agreed, but you have to be careful. [This is ok](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/b0fef92e934b25b9911b7f92d3c4e07d), but [this is not](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/ec7a5eae4abf5282572701ae636c4389). And unlike traditional closures, the compiler gives you no warning about implicit `self` references. And in many actor isolated scenarios, `deinit` is not actor-isolated and therefore cannot always reference actor isolated properties. Bottom line, you are right in this case, but it is an extremely brittle pattern.

Comment: @Rob Agreed, Swift concurrency much more complicated in terms of memory management than you can imagine at a first glance... Ecpecially it becomes complicated when you try to test concurrency code...

Comment: I think the real question would be whether it's necessary to cancel a `Task` just for the cleanup purpose. Because [this newly added documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/68482/files) attempts to explain strong/weak reference capture, providing hints on whether explicit cleanup is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To make my answer clearer, you should cancel the task manually , ideally before the view closes or the object may drop out of scope / deinit. Especially if the background task you are running has scope to carry on running a lot of work past the lifetime of the Object and View. In my opinion it is best to call this explicitly in your onCleared() function rather than rely on deinit (which personally I have found variable on when it is called / run (ie. something might still be holding a reference)).

The fact a task runs until it is cancelled explicitly is made clear in Apple documentation, regardless of whether anything has a strong reference to the Task.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task

- "A task runs regardless of whether you keep a reference to it. However, if you discard the reference to a task, you give up the ability to wait for that task’s result or cancel the task."

Comment: There is a current ban on AI generated content for SO

Comment: It looks AI generated it is introducing topics not addressed by the OP and overlooks the details from the OP. If you did this answer yourself you should revise to make it relevant to the OP.

Comment: If you read deep enough in to his code which needs some scrolling he is asking about a Task he kicks off and should he manually cancel by his own code or will it cancel when the object falls out of scope when the view moves on and the object is no longer referenced and reinit. What part is not answered. If he kicks of the task and the object drops out of scope the task will still run in the background, even without a strong reference (which was his assumption, object dropped, tsk stops), which is not correct as per apple reference I provided.

Comment: Copying from his question the key text is - "is it needed to cancel the Tasks inside of View Model manually " I answered that - Yes you do.

Comment: Thanks for the points. Does it mean I do not need to care about short running Tasks but i should cancel manually long running Tasks?

Comment: For me it comes down to a few things. If the task has potential to run for a few seconds or more, and I know I do not need the results anymore (eg. the user is navigating away from a screen), I manually cancel the tasks, calling a specific cancel function in the VM at the point the navigation away is initiated. Mainly this is for tidiness and ensuring I do not have things holding sessions / files in the background. Rarely do I find too much performance issues with the odd task running in the background but sometimes they are holding a network connection you may want to use elsewhere.